# Docker - Dockerfile: /bin/bash: catkin_init_workspace / catkin_make: command not found

Tags: ros, gazebo

I follow the guide of [kinetic - Installing from source](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing) and put the steps in a Dockerfile.

At this point, I get an error, although I follow exactly the guide, and although it works in the bash of the container created on the image before these lines, and although [Catkin command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234957/catkin-command-not-found) shows the same - in bash, not in Docker, though.

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc &&\
    source ~/.bashrc &&\
    mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src &&\
    cd ~/catkin_ws/src &&\
    catkin_init_workspace &&\
    cd ~/catkin_ws &&\
    catkin_make'
```

Commenting `catkin_init_workspace` out, it throws `catkin_make: command not found`, and keeping it, it throws `catkin_init_workspace: command not found` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Dockerfile, you cannot add the setup.bash to the .bashrc and then source the .bashrc. Instead, you want to source the setup.bash in one go:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash &&\
    mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src &&\
    cd ~/catkin_ws/src &&\
    #catkin_init_workspace &&\
    cd ~/catkin_ws &&\
    catkin_make'
```

And the line

```
catkin_init_workspace
```

can be removed, the container also works without it.

Half of the credits go to [catkin_make command not found executing by a dockerfile](https://answers.ros.org/question/312577/catkin_make-command-not-found-executing-by-a-dockerfile/?answer=312730#post-id-312730).